# releasing problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

Yes, I know that my problem is not the unique, but I have analysed many source codes but nothing works well.
I am creating an array of 100 images which will be used for UIImageView animation and after finishing animation I want to free the memory.

.h

> IBOutlet UIImageView* 1mage;

.m

> NSMutableArray* 1mageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:99];
>
> for (int i=1; i<=100; i++) {
>           [1mageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1mage_%.4d.png",i]]];
>       }
>
> 1mage.animationImages = 1mageArray;
>
> 1mage.animationDuration = 8.0;
>
> 1mage.animationRepeatCount = 0;
>
> [1mage startAnimating];
>
> [1mageArray release];

I have read Memory Management Guide, and seems, like I am doing everything okay, but debugger does not agree with me, and after playing the animation I still have 60 MB used.

Thanks in advance!

copy/paste , and I shorted variables by replacing the long text with 1. do not pay attention on this!

Comment: 1 == I ? how could that happen with copy and paste?!

Comment: If that is copied and pasted, it wouldn't even compile. You cannot begin a variable name with a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image will retain the data when you you set the animationImages. After all, it *needs* those images, doesn't it?

If you release it or set its animationImages property to nil, they might be released...

Comment: so, it seems if I do 1mage.animationImages = nil; memory will be freed ?

Comment: That sounds right, though you would want to do it *after* you've called [1mage stopAnimating]