# Strange releasing problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I have got an strange problem but I am quite sure, for you it is not. If it is so, please help me or explain.
I have an array of 39 UIImages which will be used for animating UIImageView. and after playing the animation, memory does not release.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray* actionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:38];

    for (int i=1; i<=39; i++) {
        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bg_Level1_%.4d", i] ofType:@"png"];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [path release];
        [actionArray addObject:image];
        [image release];
        NSLog(@"path rc %d image %d", [path retainCount], [image retainCount]); 
    }
    imageView.animationImages = actionArray;
    imageView.animationDuration = 4.0;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [imageView startAnimating];
    NSLog(@"RetainCount ActArr %d ImageView %d", [actionArray retainCount], [imageView retainCount]);
    [actionArray release];
    [pool drain];
    [imageView release];
    [self performSelector:@selector(playAnimation2) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)playAnimation2{
    if ([imageView isAnimating]) {
        [imageView stopAnimating];
    }
    NSLog(@"RetainCount ImageView %d",[imageView retainCount]);
}
```

there is no leaks discovered but the amount of memory allocated still is 24 mb.

or it is not so necessary ?

**EDIT:**

Sorry, my fault.
Due to many changes of my code I've got lost in it. After analysing I get it!
Thanks a lot!

The correct Code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray* actionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:38];

    for (int i=1; i<=39; i++) {
        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bg_Level1_%.4d", i] ofType:@"png"];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
//      [path release];
        [actionArray addObject:image];
        [image release];
        NSLog(@"path rc %d image %d", [path retainCount], [image retainCount]); 
    }
    imageView.animationImages = actionArray;
    imageView.animationDuration = 4.0;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [imageView startAnimating];
    NSLog(@"RetainCount ActArr %d ImageView %d", [actionArray retainCount], [imageView retainCount]);
    [actionArray release];
    [pool drain];
    [self performSelector:@selector(playAnimation2) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)playAnimation2{
    if ([imageView isAnimating]) {
        [imageView stopAnimating];
    }
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    imageView.animationImages = nil;
    NSLog(@"RetainCount ImageView %d",[imageView retainCount]);
}
```

The problem was with `[path release];`

Comment: -1 Because your code once more isn't working at all. It crashes right away because you are over-releasing *path*. Show actual code. Edit: Ok, it doesn't crash directly, but it *will* crash when the image is released.

Comment: How can I send you the whole project? The funniest thing is, that nothing crashes.

Comment: Of course it doesn't crash, because your images don't release - hence your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [releasing problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174282/releasing-problems)

Comment: You might want to start with a capacity of at least 39 if you add 39 images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong with this code.  It is a wonder it runs at all.

First:

## Do not use -retainCount.

The absolute retain count of an object is meaningless.

You should call `release` exactly same number of times that you caused the object to be retained.  No less (unless you like leaks) and, certainly, no more (unless you like crashes).

See the [Memory Management Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) for full details.

---

Now, some of the problems:

- You asked if you need to empty the array and then said *array=nil; ... doesn't work*.   Setting an array reference to nil doesn't do anything to the array;  doesn't release it or empty it.
- you are overreleasing `path`
- you are loading a series of images, sticking 'em in an array, and there isn't anything in that code that is releasing the array (or emptying it).  That your app continues to use the memory and shows no leaks sound like correct behavior.
- Why are you releasing `imageView`?  There is nothing in that code implying that you retained it and, even if it were retained via some other mechanism (IB?), that would be a really odd place to release it.

Comment: +1 ya know, i could've sworn I've seen this exact same answer before... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove all the objects from the array for it to work.

Try deleting the objects from the array, and then the array once you're finished with them.

Comment: tried to array=nil; imageView=nil; but nothing happens. allocated memory is still 23 mb. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are releasing `imageView` without retaining it anywhere, so there is probably something else wrong with you code. It seems however, that `imageView` is retained by another object ( most likely the superview), which keeps it in memory. This will also keep the array of images in memory.

If you don't need `imageView` anymore, remove it from its parent with `[imageView removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: imageView is created with IB. synthesised and released in dealloc. and still no improvement. If you have free time and desire to help I can email you this code.

Comment: I understand, but you are also releasing it here in viewDidLoad, so your dealloc might crash! If you just want to free the memory, a `imageView.animationImages = nil;` after the animation has stopped might help.

Comment: dealloc does not crash. and without releasing in viewDidLoad the same result. Maybe I am wrong - after removing the imageView and the array, the memory will be freed? is not it? Tried imageView.animationImages = nil and the same result remains.

Answer (score 1):

As we already solved here: [releasing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174282/releasing-problems)

Set `imageView.animationImages = nil;`

Also, you need to remove the `[path release];` or it will crash.

The [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) is a vital place to start with.

**Edit** *Never* rely on the retainCount property!

**Edit 2** Releasing imageView in that method is clearly a bug as well!

Comment: The Guide I have read and I doing, as I think, in a right way. strange, but the nothing crashes with [path release]; Okay. but why Allocations Instrument shows me that I still have 24mb used?

Comment: Man, have you inserted the imageView.animationImages = nil; to you playAnimation2?

Comment: Yes, it was there, but I do not know what happened, but after deleting all now it works! Thanks